# Hex to Ascii? Java

Tags: java, ascii, hex

I'm looking for a way to convert hex to ascii in Java. An example:

```
               byte temps[] = new byte[4];

               temps[0] = 0x74;
               temps[1] = 0x65;
               temps[2] = 0x73;
               temps[3] = 0x74;

               String foo = ..(temps);
               System.out.print(foo);
```

That should output "test". Anyone an idea?

I appreciate every help!

Comment: You could of course try doing your own homework

Comment: That isn't hex you're converting, it's a byte array of (presumably) ASCII character codes. There is a very big difference between writing numbers in hexadecimal notation and a hexadecimal string (which is what most people would refer to as "hex").

Comment: This is not really a question about converting hex to ascii, because you don't get e.g. a string "0x74". In your code, the "conversion" from hex is already done be the Java compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like [String(byte[] bytes, String encoding)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[]%29) ?

But watch those encodings! You're taking a set of bytes and you need to specify how to encode those as characters. You can use a version of the above that uses a default encoding, but (depending on your application) that could cause you grief further down the line. So I normally specify an encoding (most usually UTF-8).

I note you specify byte-to-ASCII, so I would explicitly specify the ASCII encoding `Charset.US-ASCII`. Don't rely on the encoding that your JVM runs with!

Comment: The question says ASCII, so the questioner should probably write ASCII in as the encoding.

Comment: Ah. It does indeed. Answer amended

Answer (score 1):

```
String foo = new String(temps);
```